# url rewriting rule in web.config using {REQUEST_URI}

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to write url rewrite rules in web.config. I need to redirect to a different domain. But for some specific cases redirection should not happen.
Description:
When input is https://abc.def.com, need to redirect it to https://hij.klm.com.
But when input is among any of the following:
1. https://abc.def.com/portal 
2. https://abc.def.com/portal.html/...anything
then redirection should not happen.

Code:

```html
<rule name="Redirect to hij.klm.com">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^abc.def.com$"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://hij.klm.com" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

This works fine when input is https://abc.def.com. It redirects to https://hij.klm.com. But when input is https://abc.def.com/portal.html it redirects to https://hij.klm.com/portal.html, which should not happen.

Comment: you should add your code to your question...

Comment: Please add your server, it's required to know if it's apache, nginx or another one.
If you have already tried some code post it even if you never succeded.

Comment: @DaFois added code.

Comment: @David Its IIS.

Comment: Any help on this